# error in Java Core in class thu_nghiem

Tags: java

I have class IP.

```
package DES;
public class IP
{
    private int a[] ={58,50,42,34,26,18,10};

    public void hoanvi(int x[])
    {
        int y[] = new int[7];
        for(int i=0;i&lt;7;i++)
        y[i] = x[i];
        for(int i=0;i&lt;7;i++)
        {
            int z = a[i];
            x[i] = y[z];
        }
    }
```

in main I writte:

```
import DES.*;

public class thu_nghiem
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a[]={58,50,42,34,26,18,10};
        IP b = new IP();
        b.hoanvi(a);
        System.out.println(a[6]);
    }
}
```

JVM messeage error !  Why ?

Answer (score 1):

On this line you take a value from the `a` array:

```
int z = a[i];
```

On the next you try to use the value from the `a` array as index of a position in `y`.

```
x[i] = y[z];
```

`y` is created to be 7 elements long, so a valid index is from 0 to 6. But *all* the values of `a` (58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18, 10) are greater than 6, so it will inevitably throw an error.

I cannot tell you how to fix it because you have not explained what this snippet of code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
package DES;

public class IP {
    private int a[] = {58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18, 10};

    public void hoanvi(int x[]) {
        int y[] = new int[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            y[i] = x[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; i++) {
                int z = a[j];
                x[i] = y[z];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ok

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 58
    at DES.IP.hoanvi(IP.java:11)
    at thu_nghiem.main(thu_nghiem.java:9)

1)                int z = a[j];
2)                 x[i] = y[z];
```

So you get index of y from array a.
And looks like mentioned index exceeds the size of array.

Whatever the code supposed to do...